# How to publish a dictionary with other dictionary inside in a topic?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, message, publisher, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm trying to publish in a topic a dictionary with other dictionary inside so other ROS node is able to access to that information, but I do not know how can I do it. Anyone has any idea?

Thanks for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/307584/how-to-publish-a-dictionary-with-other-dictionary-inside-in-a-topic?/) by [Ivan_Sanchez](https://answers.ros.org/users/38275/ivan_sanchez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2018-11-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2018-11-04**:
Which language are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I'm trying to publish in a topic a dictionary with other dictionary inside

As there are no direct dictionaries available in the message format, you have these options:

- serialize the dictionary (as suggested in the other answer) and write it into a `string` variable (or `uint8[]` if it's a binary blob).
- Flatten the dictionary to non-nested key-value pairs (`{"key1": {"key2": {"key3": "value"}}}` turns to `[("key1.key2.key3": "value")]`). Then you can use something like `diagnostic_msgs/KeyValue[]` to hold your data.
- If you have one level of nesting, you can create a custom `KeyDictValue` message, in which you store the `KeyValue[]` "dictionaries" for each "top level" key.

---

Originally posted by [moooeeeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/27965/moooeeeep/) with karma: 194 on 2021-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1